# Calling a parent scope function from deeply nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an infinitely nested data structure, where there is a top level object that has a collection of objects, and each of these objects can also have a collection of objects.

I need to iterate through this tree, which I am currently doing like so:

collection.js

```
app.directive('collection', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      collection: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'collection.html'
  };
});
```

collection.html

```
<ul>
  <member ng-repeat="member in collection" member="member"></member>
</ul>
```

member.js

```
app.directive('member', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      member: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'member.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var collection = '<collection collection="member.children"></collection>';

      if (scope.member.children) {
        $compile(collection)(scope, function(cloned, scope) {
          element.append(cloned);
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

member.html

```
<li>
  {{ member }} 
</li>
```

index.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="collectionController">
  <collection collection="collection"></collection>
</div>
```

I need to be able to click on a member, no matter how nested it is, and set the controller's selectedMember property as that member.

so something like this:

```
app.controller('collectionController', function($scope, collection) {

  collection.getCollection().then(function(collection) {
    $scope.collection = collection;
  });

  $scope.selectMember = function(member) {
    $scope.selectedMember = member;
  };

});
```

Since I'm calling a function defined in the parent scope (the controller), I think I need to pass down the selectMember function like this:

index.html

```
...
<collection collection="collection" select-member="selectMember"></collection>
...
```

collection.html

```
<member ng-repeat="member in collection" member="member" 
  select-member="selectMember()" ng-click="selectMember(member)">
</member>
```

collection.js

```
...
scope: {
  collection: '=',
  selectMember: '&selectMember'
}
...
```

member.js

```
...
scope: {
  member: '=',
  selectMember: '='
}
...
```

I just can't seem to get the function to trigger correctly and set the controller scope's selectedMember property. The parameter passed to the selectMember function is undefined.

I think it's obvious that I'm misunderstanding something about scopes, but the nested nature of the problem I have to solve isn't making things easier.

Any ideas?

Edit:
Heres a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JfxpoLLgpADs9RXSMife

Comment: perhaps a silly question: why not store a reference to the "top level owner" for each member? If this is a real tree, you've just cut out your entire need to search (if this is a graph, all bets are off)

Comment: check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/sjKSr/28/ it shows how directive talks to controller

Comment: I'm confused by `selectFolder`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think the approach you're taking is correct - i.e. passing the click handler from the outer scope. There is just some minor confusion with how to pass the handler. I wish you created a plunker, but I'll try to go blind. :)

**index.html**

```
<collection collection="collection" select-member="selectMember(member)"></collection>
```

**collection.html** template

```
<member ng-repeat="item in collection" 
        member="item" 
        select-member="selectMember({member: member})"></member>
```

**collection.js**

```
...
scope: {
  collection: '=',
  selectMember: '&'
}
...
```

**member.html** template

```
<li ng-click="selectMember({member: member})>{{ member }}</li>
```

In addition, when you add `<collection>` for `member.children`:

```
<collection collection="member.children" 
            select-member="selectMember({member: member})"></collection>
```

**member.js**

```
...
scope: {
  member: '=',
  selectMember: '&'
}
...
```

**EDIT**:

Ok, this wasn't trivial :) But it was fun.

A few modifications:

1. `select-member` shouldn't just "pass a function" as I incorrectly suggested.
2. `ng-click` wasn't properly firing when it was declared on a `member` - it was firing for both child and parent. I moved it to member.html template.
3. For clarity, I used `item` with `ng-repeat`: `ng-repeat="item in collection"`

I'm correcting the above code. I also created a fork of you [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFLM3IGdogECE3jVpqEE?p=preview).

Comment: Whenever you click on an element with children, the selectMember function is triggered twice. I'm going to try to figure out why, but you can probably figure it out before I do. Check out this fork of the plunker: "http://plnkr.co/edit/Ce9giJKeA6TK0NsEoNTT?p=preview". I added a console log on the click function to demonstrate.

Comment: I think it was because I was double-compiling the element. I changed it - see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFLM3IGdogECE3jVpqEE?p=preview)